# How to make the bitmask of a char?

Tags: c, char

I have the char `value = "ab"`, how to transform it in order to get the following bitmask `int mask = 0xab`? Is it possible to make `int mask = 0x(value)` or something like that.

Comment: Somehow I have a feeling that `a = 'ab'` is not correct by itself.

Comment: The "char" datatype stores exactly one character, yes.

Comment: I have it too but it is true  and it is valid char :)

Comment: Can you show us the code and explain what it is supposed to do? This stuff *is* valid, but it is implementation defined and rarely (like never) used.

Comment: I am communicating with COM port ant it's output data is bytes witch are returning in the following format `0 1 b8 0 5 0 0 be ba` and the first three pairs(`0 1 b8`) group together forms an hexadecimal number(`01b8`) which I should convert to decimal.

Comment: I don't see how this usecase is translating into your question.

Comment: I have the impression that the _actual_ question is summarized in the OP's previous comment and that the `unsigned char a = 'ab'` issue is wrong alltogether.

Comment: the idea is that in order to transform to hexadecimal  i have to use every character but I can not access separately `'a' or 'b'` in `'ab'`

Comment: You have a stream of *bytes*. How suddenly you got a multicharacter literal from it is a mystery.

Comment: @ХристоТодоров you completely changed your question. This is not good, in that case you should ask a new qustion. Anyway, I answered below

Comment: (In the end it turned out that the actual question was how to convert the first three bytes, most significant first, from `unsigned char buf[10];` into a single `int` and print it in decimal. Nowhere was there ever either `'ab'` or `"ab"`.)

Answer (score 5):

`'ab'` is a multicharacter constant. What exactly it does is implementation defined, so it's not going to give you the same results across different compilers. There's no guarantee that the result makes sense in any way. What you probably wanted is this:

```
const unsigned char *a = "ab";
```

Now it is a string literal, and you take its address, and assign it to a pointer. You can do the split like this:

```
char b = a[0];
char c = a[1];
```

Comment: I guess that the behaviour depends on the machine's endiannes. For me, printing the char `'ab'` prints `b`.

Comment: Yes, by C 2018 6.4.4.4 10, an implementation must accept character constants with multiple characters. The value is implementation-defined, but not the decision to accept them.

Comment: @VladRusu: Implementations may define the values of multi-character as they please. They are not bound to machine endianness.

Comment: For me on MSVC, `'ab'` is `24930`, which is `256*'a'+'b'`. Looks like it is interpreting multicharacter literals as a base 256 number. That's a cool way of using it, I guess.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And does the same implementation yield the same behaviour regardless of the machine endiannes?

Comment: @Blaze It is the same number for me, so that's why my guess was that the endiannes is what gives the result, `'ab'` being two consecutive bytes in the memory converted to `char`

Comment: but I am not declaring my variable I get it returned like that and when I try to  convert it nothing happens
`unsigned char a;
 a = some function returning 'ab'; unsigned char *b = a; printf("%c",b[0]) is not doing anything `

Comment: @ХристоТодоров `char` is only 1 byte and `'ab'` requires 2 bytes. So when you assign `unsigned char a = 'ab';` you will store just one of the `'ab'`'s 2 bytes, that is just one of the characters.

Comment: Detail: In C, `'ab'` is a multibyte _character constant_.  C does not define a multicharacter literal.  C's two literals (_string literal_, _compound literal_) can have their address taken, not so with `'ab'`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, added it to the answer.

Comment: @VladRusu: Generally, a C implementation is one specific thing: one version of one compiler with one set of compiler switches, one specific version of one standard library, one specific version of one linker, executed on one specific architecture. Changing a compiler switch (e.g., to change whether floating-point expressions may be contracted) makes it a different implementation of C. One could cluster different configurations together as one implementation provided all standard-defined and implementation-defined behavior is the same. In that case, the behavior must not depend on the machine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks. I didn't know what the behaviour is/should be in the cases where the C standard does not specify it, like in the case of multicharacter literals. I just thought it may depend on the machine's architecture as well in this cases, maybe just for some of the implementations.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you want this:

From your comment the 3 characters read from the COM port `0 1 b8` should be transformed into the number `0x1b8`.

Let's suppose this:

```
int c1 = 0;
int c2 = 0x1;
int c3 = 0xb8;
```

Then the number you want can be obtained like this:

```
int numberyouwant = (c1 << 16) | (c2 << 8) | c3;
```

Comment: How to do it if the values are assigned to variable like 
`char b = 'b8'; int c = 0xb;`?

Comment: Looks like you have a confusion between `'b8'` which is two characters and `0xb8` which is a numeric value of a single one.

Comment: Yes, how to represent the char `'b8'` into the integer `'0xb8'`, if the char is assigned to variable ?

Comment: @ХристоТодоров I'm not sure what's not clear in my answer.

Comment: I afraid we are not going anywhere. If you have a stream of characters containing `"b8"` (not `'b8'`!), then you can convert it to a single numerical value using different approaches including standard library functions such as `strtoul`.

Comment: I understand it but how to create this `ints` if I have the characters int variable?

Comment: @ХристоТодоров for example like this: `int x; char y; x = y;`

Comment: @ХристоТодоров you probably need to enhance your question and tell us what _exactly_ you're reading from the COM port. Maybe you should think it over and ask a whole new question.

Comment: but then it is giving me the ASCII table value

Comment: @ХристоТодоров To make it clear - your description is not making much sense and each comment is making it worse. Please, rethink your question and provide more information in a structured way as suggested above.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Your suggestion works but how to make it universal. For example if I am getting this char variables as params of an function and want to  transform them in integers like `0xb8`.

Comment: @ХристоТодоров this is turning into a whole different question. Please ask a new question with that specific issue.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have the char `value = "ab"`, how to transform it in order to get the following bitmask `int mask = 0xab`? Is it possible to make `int mask = 0x(value)` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char buffer[] = "ab" ;
  int x = strtol(buffer, NULL, 16);
  printf("x in hexadecimal = %x\nx in decimal = %d\n", x, x);
  return 0;
}
```

Or a bit more complicated, if you just want to pick 2 chars in the middle of a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char buffer[] = "ab12345" ;
  char tempbuffer[3];
  tempbuffer[0] = buffer[0];
  tempbuffer[1] = buffer[1];
  tempbuffer[2] = 0;
  int x = strtol(tempbuffer, NULL, 16);
  printf("x in hexadecimal = %x\nx in decimal = %d\n", x, x);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the function I use but it is no doing anything:
`void procedeData(unsigned char buff[]){
    int WEIGHT_H = strtol(buff[0], NULL, 16);
    int WEIGHT_M = strtol(buff[1], NULL, 16);
    int WEIGHT_L = strtol(buff[2], NULL, 16);

    int numberyouwant = (buff[0] << 16) | (buff[0] << 8) | buff[0];

    printf("%d , %d , %d\n",WEIGHT_H, WEIGHT_M, WEIGHT_L);
    printf("%d, ", numberyouwant);
}` even the `printf` dont print anything

Comment: @ХристоТодоров Please ask anothe question, and don't put code einto comments, it's unreadable as you can see.

Comment: I cant, I have to wait 90mins.

Comment: @ХристоТодоров In the meantime you can read the documentation of [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) and play around witht the sample provided there. You might find the answer to your problem by doing so by yourself. Also read this for further question: [mcve]. BTW you cannot format code in comments, therefore don't post code in comments except simple oneliners

Comment: @ХристоТодоров Why don't you use the code in _this answer_ (and only this answer, not the others) as it is, instead of adding unnecessary stuff to it. Also read the documentation of `strtol`. And learn the difference between characters and strings.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I play a little and if I run the function as so `strtol("b8", NULL, 16)` everything is perfect but if I run it like  this `strtol('b8', NULL, 16)` I am getting the same result which mu program give.

Comment: @ХристоТодоров Well, don't run it with `'b8'` because it's completely incorrect!

Comment: @ХристоТодоров forget more than one char between `' '`, it's not what you think it is.

Comment: Yes but I the value `'b8'` is in char variable and I dont know how to make it `"b8"`.

Comment: I know but this is how I get it from COM port output.

Comment: @ХристоТодоров Please show us what sequence of _bytes_ you're reading from the COM port. It's really unclear

Comment: @ХристоТодоров Unless your COM port inputs broken C code which you are forced to compile, you are not getting it as `char value = 'b8';`. If you have written that code yourself, then that code is wrong, change it to, e.g., `char value[] = "b8";`. If you are reading individual characters, then you can't read more than one into a single `char`.

Comment: This are the bytes `0 1 a4 0 5 0 0 aa 40`, and I am reading them with this
`unsigned char buf[10];<br/>
        int i = 0;<br/>
        do {<br/>
        cnt = RS232_PollComport(cport_nr,(buf+i), 1);<br/>
        printf("%x ",buf[i]);<br/>
        i++;<br/>
        }<br/>
        while(cnt>0);<br/>`

Comment: @ХристоТодоров So you don't have `char value`, you have `unsigned char buf[10]`: simply NUL-terminate `buf` (`buf[i] = '\0';`) when you have read enough and pass `buf` (not `buf[something]`) to `strtoul`. `buf` is an array of 10 characters, `buf[i]` is a single character in that array.

Comment: Okay but now `strtol(buf, NULL, 16);` is returning `0` always

Comment: @ХристоТодоров Yes, because you didn't actually receive a valid number as a string from the port. Sorry, but this is quite pointless since you keep revealing the necessary information a little by little and it has nothing to do with what you asked in the question.

Comment: I receive this `0 1 a4 0 5 0 0 aa 40`

Comment: I need to use only the first 3 bytes so I have to make new unsigned char with only them there?

Comment: @ХристоТодоров It won't help, because none of the characters you've read are ASCII digits and no subset of them will ever return anything valid when passed to `strtol`. At this point it is completely unclear what you even want as the output.

Comment: the first three(`0 1 a4`) when you put together are making hexadecimal number which I want to derive and transform to decimal. This whole array is declared as a unsigned char with this elements `0 1 a4 0 5 0 0 aa 40`; The number is 01a4 which is equal to 420 in decimal.

Comment: @ХристоТодоров `int value = (buf[0] << 16) | (buf[1] << 8) | buf[2]; printf("%d\n", value);`

Comment: @ХристоТодоров that was exactly what I answered in my first answer. Accept it at least. Sigh...